# enrichment using MarkLogic java api : cts.entityHighlight

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

[image]

Here I am doing MarkLogic enrichment with `cts.entityHighlight`. Is there any MarkLogic java API that do same things?

Answer (score 0):

The MarkLogic Java API is a client library, and not designed to provide literal access to ad hoc instructions like above. You best encapsulate your code on server-side, and make it available for outside usage. Depending on how and when you want to use it, you could consider using a REST extension, or a REST transform for instance, but perhaps in your case Data Services makes most sense. You can find documentation on it here:

https://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/guide/java/DataServices

HTH!